# Getting NULL in a TableViewController when Trying to delete a row - the row is deleted with viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, tableview

I have a simple program which is a TableViewController which calls a ModalViewController, the user adds some text into a text field, clicks save and it gets added back to the TableViewController.

I am trying to swipe to delete the rows and when I do, the values change to "NULL" and the row remains there. If I relaunch the app or go to another View Controller and back again, the row then disappears.

My code looks like this:

```
@interface NewTimelineViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *transactions;
@end

@implementation NewTimelineViewController

@synthesize transactions = _transactions;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{       
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)])
    {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.transactions.count;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.transactions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            //abort();
            //[self.tableView reloadData];       
        }
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Persons";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSManagedObject *transaction = [self.transactions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [transaction valueForKeyPath:@"whoBy.name"], [transaction valueForKeyPath:@"gifting.amount"]]];

    return cell;
}
```

I know it's something fairly easy; to me it looks like the actual row isn't getting deleted or reloaded in this view, but the moment this TableView appears again, it's gone.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the object from your datasource as well (probably an array) then reload the table view (either through reload or a more unobtrusive way like reloadRowsAtIndexPaths)

Comment: Thanks William - I knew I was missing something easy. I removed the value from the array as you mentioned and then did the reloadData and that worked. I will now try removing it using the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths but thanks so much - just needed that nudge!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an implementation for the 
    `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` UITableView's datasource method.

In this method you should remove the value from the transactions array and then either call tableView's reloadData or deleteRowsAtIndexPaths for the indexpath of the row that the user has selected to delete.

Comment: Hi Nikos, thanks so much for the reply. With the first response, that was what I implemented and I got it working like a charm; thanks very much for your assistance and for replying here.

Answer (score 0):

You just deleted the object from the database,

```
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.transactions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

but you forgot to delete it from the data source `self.transactions` after succeeding,

```
[self.transactions removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and remember to reload the table view or delete the table view cell of the deleted object.

Comment: Hi Klaudz, thanks very much for your response - that is very helpful and I got it working with the first response and your code snippet is exactly what I have put in and it works like a treat. Thanks for replying here - appreciate it!